# Elastic search by http get request to receive Csv as response

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to generate `csv` as response from [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) index. For that I am using Plugin as:

```
$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install org.codelibs:elasticsearch-dataformat:5.3.0
```

As provided in the git the query format should be like this

```
curl -o /tmp/data.csv -XGET "localhost:9200/{index}/{type}/_data?format=csv&source=
```

My requirement is to write a query where field `name = Anuj`. This is how I'm writing the query.

```
http://bgl-mong-ros121:9500/mydata/term/_data?format=csv&_source=_search?q=name:Anuj&pretty=true
```

Response I'm as receiving:

```
{
  "_index" : "mydata",
  "_type" : "term",
  "_id" : "_data",
  "found" : false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your query string, write it like this instead:

```
http://bgl-mong-ros121:9500/mydata/term/_data?format=csv&_source=_search&q=name:Anuj&pretty=true
                                                                        ^
                                                                        |
                                                                 change ? to &
```

**UPDATE**:

Also try this:

```
http://bgl-mong-ros121:9500/mydata/term/_data?format=csv&source={"_source":["_search"],"query":{"match":{"name":"Anuj"}}}
```

Comment: thanks but  not working q as a invalid parameter now @Val

Comment: My bad, the `q` parameter needs to be named `source` instead

Comment: http://bgl-mong-ros121:9500/mydata/term/_data?format=csv&_source=_search&source=name:Anuj&pretty=true
404 not found

Comment: "type": "illegal_argument_exception",  "reason": "request [/mydata/term/_data] contains unrecognized parameter: [source] -> did you mean [_source]?" 
If i replace it _source than again 404 not found

Comment: Can you try without `source` and only `format=csv`? What do you get?

Comment: http://addasabove/term/_data?format=csv
404 not found 
{
    "_index": "mydata",
    "_type": "term",
    "_id": "_data",
    "found": false
}

Comment: Ok, then it simply means that your plugin is not installed correctly. Do you see its name appear in the logs  when ES starts up?

Comment: When Es server starts i m able to see data format plugin  but things are not working @Val

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: Irs has been resolved. 5.4 version i m using but there is one more problem now the default heap allocated to plugin is low so i can't query for a big result set How i can change the default allocation @Val

Comment: How much memory does your machine have? can you provide the output you get from `ps -edf | grep java`?

Comment: Its nearly 360GB

Comment: memory, not disk space :-)

Comment: I m not using local system server has been hosted. Its nearly 48Gb total memory allocated.
java -Xms16g -Xmx16g